# In IntelliJ IDEA how do I replace text with a new line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wanted to replace all commas with commas and a newline using IntelliJ IDEA's replace function. What do I put in the search box? In vim I'd use `&\r`.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You need to check the Regex box and use "\n" for the new line character:

[image]

Comment: And how can you remove an empty line using same regex. :)

Comment: @muasif80 in notepad++ editor I can search for \n\n and replace with \n or search for YXYZ\n and replace with XYZ or  \nABC and replace with just ABC ... depends on document, but in genereal can search for \n and in replace part leave that out

Answer (score 118):

Use Multiline button, no Regex is needed.
[image]

edit: the multiline button is missing since IntelliJ 15, but you can enable it by clicking into the textfield and pressing `Alt+Enter` or `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: I'm using 15, and it looks like the multiline feature is no more. Why would they remove such a useful feature?

Comment: This still exists, select multiple lines, then click `CTRL+F`, *then* click `CTRL+R`, it seems to be a hidden feature, but still works in that case as previous versions

Comment: It's even easier now -- a visible return carriage arrow appears within the find or replace boxes -- clicking it will insert a newline.

Comment: is there any way to make it keep indentation? If I replace a string `apples` that starts at col 16 with `apples\nbananas`, bananas will be at column 0

Comment: @TomM there is no way afaik, unless you write a plugin.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: I pasted text with a new line in the replace part, preserved that and replaced it.

Answer (score 17):

For Intellij Ultimate 2017.3 on Mac, `command-shift-enter` works

Comment: This answer is legitimate and work for search and replace in IntelliJ IDEA, PHPStorm and WebStorm where the user wants to replace an instance of `\n` with actual new line.
Please do not downvote useful answers.

Answer (score 9):

Hit `CTRL+F` and check the `regex` checkbox. Then search for `,` and replace it with `,\n`.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way that I have done it is to use the regular expression form of replace.

[image]

Chances are that you don't want to replace the `{`, but just keep in my escaping them if you do want to do so.

Comment: Ha-ha, looks like everyone knows this.

Comment: It does, and it seems like you're faster with Paint :). PS: If you have not tried it, then I strongly suggest the Darcula! It is so much easier on my eyes.

Comment: It's PicPick I'm using. I tried Idea Darcula Theme, but I guess I'm too much used to the default colors.

Answer (score 7):

On intellij Ultimate 2017.1:

I didn't need regex. But I could make the multiline replace appear.

- I entered \n in the field I wanted to replace
- I placed my cursor in the field where I wanted to enter the replacement text, and clicked Ctrl-Shift + Enter. Here I just hit return

[image]

Comment: Command-Shift + Enter on Mac

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for the old multiline replace in inteliJ with version > 15.x. It seems somewhat hidden, but if you select multiple lines > click `CTRL+F`, then immediately click `CTRL+R` you are presented with the original multiline replace.

This is working on Mac `IntelliJ 2016.1.3` with ⌘+F > ⌘+R

[image]

Comment: you just press ALT+Enter, with the focus in the textfield

Comment: Even with this trick it is not possible to enter multiple lines in the replace field.

Comment: Its working for me fine within `IntelliJ 2016.1.3` on MAC, ⌘ + F > ⌘ + R

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach would be to add `(?m)` in front of the regular expression, which turns on the multi line mode. This has the advantage that you can also use it in the global file search (Ctrl-Shift-F).

Example: `(?m)\{(.|\n)*?\}` searches for multi-line blocks surrounded by curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

The is related but not exactly what you asked.  But I needed it and I can imagine others do to. 
So I had the problem in Node.js where I wanted to split a reject into call into a log and reject for clarity

`reject(error)`

into

`appLogger.log(error, 'error')
 reject(error)`

In normal mode, I did find and replace

> Find: `reject(error)`
>
> Replace: `appLogger.log(error, 'error')\n reject(error)`

Then in regex mode I did a second find and replace:

> Find: `\\n`
>
> Replace `\n`

Comment: If your answer is helpful, but not actually answering this question, it's better to ask a new question and add your answer there. We always welcome useful new questions and answers, and it's encouraged to answer your own question if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> **while the replaced text is selected**:

This works for *Replace in Path* (WebStorm 2018.2.3):

[image]

see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207696505-Multi-line-search-and-replace?flash_digest=5eb7905eda771e5ef2e27856821bc57ae2267327)