# WebStorm 11 - multiline button for search/replace missing?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I recently upgraded WebStorm to version 11 (on OS X El Capitan). I can't find the multiline button any more.

I can start a multiline search if I select multiple lines of code and press <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd>, and a multiline replace by doing the same and pressing <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd> followed by <kbd>Cmd + R</kbd> but I can't find a way to do it in one step or without taking code as basis for the search. I can make a line break with <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>, but only once.

Before updating ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21221346/3085985)): 
[image: Multiline search button]

After updating: 
[image: No multiline search button]

Any ideas how I get the button back or at least a shortcut for multiline search? I did not find any setting for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> seems to enter multiline mode completely, so I can use normal <kbd>Enter</kbd> after using this shortcut. Ok, that's an almost sufficient workaround, there seems to be no other solution as the issues by LazyOne prove. Hopefully they will add the button again...

Comment: It is now **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter** on Windows and **Cmd** + **Shift** + **Enter** on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Please watch (star/vote/comment) these tickets for updates:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145712
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145720