# How to do multi-line search and replace in Intellij 2016.2?

Tags: intellij-idea

It looks like the old multi line search and replace disappeared at or before IntelliJ 2016.2. In this version, is there still a way to do multi-line search and replace?

Comment: I still have it in my 2016.2.  If it's one file, use Ctrl-R.  If's it's across the entire project, use Ctrl-Shift-R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Intellij IDEA how do I replace text with a new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219884/in-intellij-idea-how-do-i-replace-text-with-a-new-line)